redis rdb saving fails with signal 31
My redis is not able to do the background saving, my log is full with logs like these:
2817:M 23 Nov 2024 11:28:59.938 - DB 0: 27168 keys (0 volatile) in 32768 slots HT.
2817:M 23 Nov 2024 11:28:59.938 . 1 clients connected (0 replicas), 13098864 bytes in use
2817:M 23 Nov 2024 11:29:00.039 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
2817:M 23 Nov 2024 11:29:00.043 * Background saving started by pid 29696
29696:C 23 Nov 2024 11:29:00.051 - Fork CoW for RDB: current 0 MB, peak 0 MB, average 0 MB
2817:M 23 Nov 2024 11:29:00.549 # Background saving terminated by signal 31

Unfortunately I am not able to get more verbose logs about this (the above is with loglevel=debug), so I really do not know how to fix/improve this.
I already configured my machine to allow memory overcommit:
cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
1

redis-server -v
Redis server v=7.0.15 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.3.0 bits=32 build=8fef3e995a542118

It seems redis is sometimes able to do the saving:
ls /var/lib/redis -al
total 4104
drwxr-x---  2 redis redis    4096 Nov 23 11:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 28 root  root     4096 Nov 13 10:14 ..
-rw-rw----  1 redis redis 4193638 Nov 16 09:42 dump.rdb

and during a restart it seems to work as well:
# systemctl restart redis
# ls /var/lib/redis -al
total 8200
drwxr-x---  2 redis redis    4096 Nov 23 11:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 28 root  root     4096 Nov 13 10:14 ..
-rw-rw----  1 redis redis 4193638 Nov 16 09:42 dump.rdb
-rw-rw----  1 redis redis 4194304 Nov 23 11:46 temp-2817.rdb

But why is it not working in the background?

filed a bug report on github for this: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/13671
